# error "webpage is not available" for my website

Tags: wordpress, iis, dns, web

I have a wordpress website. its about 3 days when I want to enter the website I see the error"This web page is not available" I checked both DNS and IIS on the server and they work truely but I couldn't access my website.help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than 1 possible answers for this.

#### First thing to do:

Click the Chrome menu and go for Settings --> Click Show Advanced settings --> Click Change proxy settings.

This would open the Internet Explorer Properties dialog. Click **LAN** (almost bottom) Settings. Make sure that the "Automatically detect settings" checkbox is selected.

Click **OK** for all dialog boxes.

#### Second method

I get this error many times when I'm back to my laptop and my router (Modem) is still trying to connect to the Internet for the first time but my laptop was back in action from a sleep mode or from a lid down (hibernate) mode.

So, you either need to wait (but 3 days is enough) you need to check for the IP or DNS or LAN settings, they must be messing up your whole thing.